# change the who of google calendar event with gdata framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

```
$gdataCal= new Zend_gdata_calendar($client);
//on retrouve l'event a partir de eventURL stocké lors de la création
$event = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventEntry($id_event);
$who= $gdataCal->newWho();// $who objet de type Zend_Gdata_Extension_Who

//les nouvelles valeurs du who
$email ="cn21lqqt8jeb9qgulpra6bj948%40group.calendar.google.com";
$rel = 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.organizer'  ;
$valueString ='alain developpeur';
$who->setEmail($email);
$who->setRel($rel);
$who->setValueString($valueString);
//$who->setDom($who_old[0]->getDOM());//bizarre mais???
//méthode magic ou setteurs
//$event->who= array($who);
$event->setWho($who);
//on affiche les propriétés du nouveau who pour voir les changements


echo'<br >lemail  est   :  '.$who->getEmail();

echo'<br >la value string est   :  '.$who->getValueString();

echo'<br >la rel est   :  '.$who->getRel();


//on sauve on spécifie le type de classe dans lequel on veut sauver
// $event->save(Zend_Gdata_EventEntry);???

 $event->save(Zend_Gdata_App_Entry);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what do you wish to know because of your comments on French. To share event with $email you should use:

```
$who = $gdataCal->newWho();
$who->setEmail($email);
$newEvent->setWho(array($who));
```